# My mongodb aggregation query is taking too much time. How can I enhance the performance?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm joining two collection using aggregation and using "output" to generate a new collection with the joined data, but it's taking too much time(never ends). 
How can I enhance the performance?
The collection A has 260k documents and collection B has 17.2m.

I have already tested the same script with different data sets and it works fine. At first glance, issue seems to be related with the size of collections.

```
db.colection_A.aggregate([
    {
        $match : { property_X: "X" }
    },
    {   "$lookup":
        {
            from: "collection_B",
            localField: "property_A",
            foreignField: "property_B",
            as: "joined_data"
        }
    },
    {   $unwind:
        {
            path: "$joined_data",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
        }
    },
    {   $project: 
        {   
            "_id": 0,
            "joined_data": 1
         } 
    },
    {   $replaceRoot: 
            { newRoot: "$joined_data" } 
    },
    //{ $limit : 1 }
    { $out: "new_collection"}
    ]);
```

Expected result is creation of the collection "new_collection" containing data filtered in the "match" and "lookup" conditions.

Comment: Best thing to do would be to add index on the field which you are using as a condition in your case add index on localfield

Comment: Do you have any indexes defined on the `colection_A`? If so, please post the details. Also, generating a _query plan_ (using `explain`) can reveal any performance related issues.

Comment: I have created an index in "collection_B" using the "foreignField" and is running faster now. Will do few more tests and reply here later with final results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The aggregation query was working fine, the problem was related with indexing in Mongo.
After creation of the index, the query performed much better.
Index was created with:

```
db.collection_B.createIndex( { property_B: 1 } );
```